# Difference between Machine Learning and explicit programming

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I'm newbie to data science field. So I'm trying to understand his basics step by step. And among his most important fields, we find machine learning.

I found this definition :

"the machine learning is the field of study to give the ability to a Machine to learn without being explicitly programmed."

What's still fuzzy for me is how can we give a machine the ability to learn without being programmed !!

Can anyone please make this clear for me ?

Comment: Accurately defining machine learning in a single sentence is somewhere between very, very hard and impossible. I guess the point here is - the machine can learn (how to make decisions e.g.), from data alone, without requiring a human expert that tells the machine exactly what to do. Of course a self-learning machine has to be programmed as well... However this is just a tiny aspect of machine learning and I really dislike this definition.

Comment: @cel think you. I'll focus in the link in the answer to more understand :)

Comment: ML algorithms do not care about the problem you are solving (to a suprising extent) ... they are generic such that they work across many problem domains ... whereas traditional explicit programming is typically very domain specific ... an analogy : neural networks ( ML ) inside your head process vision, cognition, taste, sensory-motor whereas your muscles ( traditional explicit approach ) are only good to the extent they contract to pull together disparate bones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With machine learning you can make a program that will learn things on its own, so with one program for example it can learn to detect if a there is a cat in the picture. Now you don't have to tell the program if each picture has a cat in it or not, the program will learn that itself using machine learning.

You can use different methods of machine learning, for example supervised learning where you give the program a set of example data points with labels to indicate the meaning of that data.
With unsupervised learning you don't give labels with the examples, so the program has to find the clusters/patterns on it's own.
Maybe this can help you learn it:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/in-depth-introduction-to-machine-learning-in-15-hours-of-expert-videos/

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I'll concentrate to this link to more understand :)